# resizableImageWithCapInsets issue in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage, ios7

I am following [MessagesTableViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/MessagesTableViewController) and there is method of starching of UIImage for bubble view to strech as per text size. It is working fine with older ios version but in `ios7`, it is displaying light color borders as we set `UIEdgeInsetsMake` as below.

```
+ (UIImage *)bubbleDefaultIncoming
{
  return [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-chat-white.png"] makeStretchableDefaultIncoming];
}

- (UIImage *)makeStretchableDefaultIncoming
{

  return [self resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15.0f,20.0f, 15.0f, 20.0f)
                            resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
}
```

Here i attached 2 snapshot for `ios6` and `ios7` which describe how bubble View is behaving strange with ios7 though code is same.
[image: ios6 bubble] and [image: ios7 bubble]

Someone has also same issue and reported in [***GITHUB HERE***](https://github.com/jessesquires/MessagesTableViewController/issues/50) 
I reviewed code so much and it seems that there is issue with `resizableImageWithCapInsets` in ios7. It generates borders as we set `UIEdgeInsetsMake`in the method.

Anyone has idea or solution to remove the borders from bubble view and make same as ios6 bubble view?

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i read that page on github, i got to know that it is an apple bug.

Comment: Is there any overcome to solve?

Comment: Yes, you can fix this by ensuring the CGRect is all even and also the table view cells have an even height.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Transparent lines are added in iOS 7 when the width or height is a number with floating point. As a workaround, you can round this numbers

Comment: You can see, i am already using round numbers `UIEdgeInsetsMake(15.0f,20.0f, 15.0f, 20.0f)`. But still there are white lines.

Comment: round numbers should be used for the cgrectarea where you're drawing

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure that the CGRect you are drawing the image into is an even number and not a number with a floating point.

In addition to this if you have a UITableView with TabViewCells that have different heights you also need to need to ensure those cells all have heights that are an even number and not a number with a floating point.

Answer (score 1):

i can confirm that both answers are right, but since you are using the same framework as me i going to give you a snippet to help.

just floor or ceil the size of the bubble and you are good to go.

```
- (CGRect)bubbleFrame
{
    CGSize bubbleSize = [JSBubbleView bubbleSizeForText:self.text];
    return CGRectMake((self.type == JSBubbleMessageTypeOutgoing ? floor(self.frame.size.width - bubbleSize.width) : 0),
                  kMarginTop,
                  floor(bubbleSize.width),
                  floor(bubbleSize.height));
}
```

edit: the position too need to be rounded up or down, since the kMarginTop already is you only need for it when it's a outgoing bubble. peace